# Resolution not in xrandr and make new Resolution permenent?

Tags: xorg, resolution, intel-graphics, monitor, xrandr

I am using a monitor which its native (optimal) resolution is 1600*900. but xrandr doesn't show any resolution above "1024x768".
I can change to my native resoution by issuing these 3 commands:

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync   

xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1600x900_60.00"  

xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

but I have to do it each time I reboot. I searched the wiki and found I can write an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`.

I wrote this but **it doesn't work". I don't know where I am doing wrong?

```
Section "Device" 
Identifier  "Intel i915" 
  Option   "VGA1" #"VGA screen" 
  Driver      "intel"
EndSection 
Section "Monitor" 
  Identifier  "Primary Monitor" 
  Modeline    "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -Hsync +Vsync 
  Option      "PreferredMode" "1600x900" 
EndSection 
Section "Screen" 
     Identifier    "Screen0" 
     Device        "VGA1" 
     DefaultDepth  24 
     SubSection "Display" 
     Depth        24 
     Modes   "1600x900_60.00" 
EndSubSection 
EndSection
```

also here is the output of my `$> xrandr -q`

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6820312/

Comment: I know that my file is being read because after I reboot with the `10-monitor.conf` my `$> xrandr -q` output becomes:==> [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6820329/)

Comment: I use `intel` Xeon 3Gen onboard graphic chipset.
and `i915` driver.

Comment: Is it a real machine installation or a virtual machine?

Comment: @steeldriver ; actual macine no virtual

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I solved by putting the xrandr commands in ~/.xprofile

Comment: the problem with this kind of approach is that it effects too late in the booting stage and cause all sorts of problems; from `feh` not setting the wallpaper right to ugly resized components in system tray and so on...